# d3js tool tip size/width change

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

This is a d3js line chart which i found from their size.i want to increase the size of the black tooltip details pop up in the chart. Does anyone know how to increase the size of the tool tip in this line chart? I tried sometime  but could not find how to increase or decrease it.
[image]

```js
;( function() {
  var data = {
    lineChart : [
      {
        date  : '2006-02-22',
        label : 'foo',
        value : 950
      },
      {
        date  : '2006-08-22',
        label : 'bar',
        value : 1000
      },
      {
        date  : '2007-01-11',
        label : 'baz',
        value : 700
      },
      {
        date  : '2008-10-01',
        label : 'boing',
        value : 534
      },
      {
        date  : '2009-02-24',
        label : 'loool',
        value : 1423
      },
      {
        date  : '2010-12-30',
        label : 'YEAH',
        value : 1222
      },
      {
        date  : '2011-05-15',
        label : 'Hurray',
        value : 948
      },
      {
        date  : '2012-04-02',
        label : 'WTF',
        value : 1938
      },
      {
        date  : '2013-08-19',
        label : 'OMG',
        value : 1245
      },
      {
        date  : '2013-11-11',
        label : 'ROFL',
        value : 888
      }
    ],
    pieChart  : [
      {
        color       : 'red',
        description : 'Ipsem lorem text goes here. And foo goes bar goes baz. That\'s up!!!',
        title       : 'flowers',
        value       : 0.62
      },
      {
        color       : 'blue',
        description : 'Another ipsem text goes here. And baz goes bar goes foo. Oh yeah, whazzz up?',
        title       : 'trains',
        value       : 0.38
      }
    ]
  };
  
  var DURATION = 1500;
  var DELAY    = 500;
  
  /**
   * draw the fancy line chart
   *
   * @param {String} elementId elementId
   * @param {Array}  data      data
   */
  function drawLineChart( elementId, data ) {
    // parse helper functions on top
    var parse = d3.time.format( '%Y-%m-%d' ).parse;
    // data manipulation first
    data = data.map( function( datum ) {
      datum.date = parse( datum.date );
      
      return datum;
    } );
    
    // TODO code duplication check how you can avoid that
    var containerEl = document.getElementById( elementId ),
        width       = containerEl.clientWidth,
        height      = width * 0.4,
        margin      = {
          top    : 30,
          right  : 10,
          left   : 10 
        },
        
        detailWidth  = 98,
        detailHeight = 55,
        detailMargin = 10,

        container   = d3.select( containerEl ),
        svg         = container.select( 'svg' )
                                .attr( 'width', width )
                                .attr( 'height', height + margin.top ),

        x          = d3.time.scale().range( [ 0, width - detailWidth ] ),
        xAxis      = d3.svg.axis().scale( x )
                                  .ticks ( 8 )
                                  .tickSize( -height ),
        xAxisTicks = d3.svg.axis().scale( x )
                                  .ticks( 16 )
                                  .tickSize( -height )
                                  .tickFormat( '' ),
        y          = d3.scale.linear().range( [ height, 0 ] ),
        yAxisTicks = d3.svg.axis().scale( y )
                                  .ticks( 12 )
                                  .tickSize( width )
                                  .tickFormat( '' )
                                  .orient( 'right' ),
        
        area = d3.svg.area()
                      .interpolate( 'linear' )
                      .x( function( d )  { return x( d.date ) + detailWidth / 2; } )
                      .y0( height )
                      .y1( function( d ) { return y( d.value ); } ),

        line = d3.svg.line()
                  .interpolate( 'linear' )
                  .x( function( d ) { return x( d.date ) + detailWidth / 2; } )
                  .y( function( d ) { return y( d.value ); } ),
        
        startData = data.map( function( datum ) {
                      return {
                        date  : datum.date,
                        value : 0
                      };
                    } ),
        
        circleContainer;

    // Compute the minimum and maximum date, and the maximum price.
    x.domain( [ data[ 0 ].date, data[ data.length - 1 ].date ] );
    // hacky hacky hacky :(
    y.domain( [ 0, d3.max( data, function( d ) { return d.value; } ) + 700 ] );

    svg.append( 'g' )
        .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--xAxisTicks' )
        .attr( 'transform', 'translate(' + detailWidth / 2 + ',' + height + ')' )
        .call( xAxisTicks );

    svg.append( 'g' )
        .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--xAxis' )
        .attr( 'transform', 'translate(' + detailWidth / 2 + ',' + ( height + 7 ) + ')' )
        .call( xAxis );
    
    svg.append( 'g' )
      .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--yAxisTicks' )
      .call( yAxisTicks );
    
    // Add the line path.
    svg.append( 'path' )
        .datum( startData )
        .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--areaLine' )
        .attr( 'd', line )
        .transition()
        .duration( DURATION )
        .delay( DURATION / 2 )
        .attrTween( 'd', tween( data, line ) )
        .each( 'end', function() {
          drawCircles( data );
        } );
    
    
    // Add the area path.
    svg.append( 'path' )
        .datum( startData )
        .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--area' )
        .attr( 'd', area )
        .transition()
        .duration( DURATION )
        .attrTween( 'd', tween( data, area ) );
    
    // Helper functions!!!
    function drawCircle( datum, index ) {
      circleContainer.datum( datum )
                    .append( 'circle' )
                    .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--circle' )
                    .attr( 'r', 0 )
                    .attr(
                      'cx',
                      function( d ) {
                        return x( d.date ) + detailWidth / 2;
                      }
                    )
                    .attr(
                      'cy',
                      function( d ) {
                        return y( d.value );
                      }
                    )
                    .on( 'mouseenter', function( d ) {
                      d3.select( this )
                        .attr(
                          'class',
                          'lineChart--circle lineChart--circle__highlighted' 
                        )
                        .attr( 'r', 7 );
                      
                        d.active = true;
                        
                        showCircleDetail( d );
                    } )
                    .on( 'mouseout', function( d ) {
                      d3.select( this )
                        .attr(
                          'class',
                          'lineChart--circle' 
                        )
                        .attr( 'r', 6 );
                      
                      if ( d.active ) {
                        hideCircleDetails();
                        
                        d.active = false;
                      }
                    } )
                    .on( 'click touch', function( d ) {
                      if ( d.active ) {
                        showCircleDetail( d )
                      } else {
                        hideCircleDetails();
                      }
                    } )
                    .transition()
                    .delay( DURATION / 10 * index )
                    .attr( 'r', 6 );
    }
    
    function drawCircles( data ) {
      circleContainer = svg.append( 'g' );

      data.forEach( function( datum, index ) {
        drawCircle( datum, index );
      } );
    }
    
    function hideCircleDetails() {
      circleContainer.selectAll( '.lineChart--bubble' )
                      .remove();
    }
    
    function showCircleDetail( data ) {
      var details = circleContainer.append( 'g' )
                        .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--bubble' )
                        .attr(
                          'transform',
                          function() {
                            var result = 'translate(';
                            
                            result += x( data.date );
                            result += ', ';
                            result += y( data.value ) - detailHeight - detailMargin;
                            result += ')';
                            
                            return result;
                          }
                        );
      
      details.append( 'path' )
              .attr( 'd', 'M2.99990186,0 C1.34310181,0 0,1.34216977 0,2.99898218 L0,47.6680579 C0,49.32435 1.34136094,50.6670401 3.00074875,50.6670401 L44.4095996,50.6670401 C48.9775098,54.3898926 44.4672607,50.6057129 49,54.46875 C53.4190918,50.6962891 49.0050244,54.4362793 53.501875,50.6670401 L94.9943116,50.6670401 C96.6543075,50.6670401 98,49.3248703 98,47.6680579 L98,2.99898218 C98,1.34269006 96.651936,0 95.0000981,0 L2.99990186,0 Z M2.99990186,0' )
              .attr( 'width', detailWidth )
              .attr( 'height', detailHeight );
      
      var text = details.append( 'text' )
                        .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--bubble--text' );
      
      text.append( 'tspan' )
          .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--bubble--label' )
          .attr( 'x', detailWidth / 2 )
          .attr( 'y', detailHeight / 3 )
          .attr( 'text-anchor', 'middle' )
          .text( data.label );
      
      text.append( 'tspan' )
          .attr( 'class', 'lineChart--bubble--value' )
          .attr( 'x', detailWidth / 2 )
          .attr( 'y', detailHeight / 4 * 3 )
          .attr( 'text-anchor', 'middle' )
          .text( data.value );
    }
    
    function tween( b, callback ) {
      return function( a ) {
        var i = d3.interpolateArray( a, b );

        return function( t ) {
          return callback( i ( t ) );
        };
      };
    }
  }
  

  function ಠ_ಠ() {
  
    drawLineChart(    'lineChart',    data.lineChart );
  }
  
  // yeah, let's kick things off!!!
  ಠ_ಠ();
  
})();
```

```css
/**
 * Variable power
 */
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 25%);
  background-size: 4px 4px;
}
body ul {
  list-style: none;
}
body ul, body li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.chart {
  min-height: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}

.chart--headline, .chart--subHeadline {
  text-align: center;
}

.chart--headline {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.chart--headline:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 133%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -12.5%;
  border-top: 1px dashed #999999;
}

.chart--subHeadline {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.charts--container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .charts--container {
    max-width: 700px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 10%;
    margin: 5em auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2em 2em #333;
  }
}

.charts--headline {
  text-align: center;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}

.lineChart--area {
  fill: url(#lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea);
}

.lineChart--areaLine {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #6bb7c7;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

.lineChart--bubble--label {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #6bb7c7;
  font-size: 12.6px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.lineChart--bubble--value {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.lineChart--circle {
  fill: #6bb7c7;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

.lineChart--circle__highlighted {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #3f94a7;
}

.lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top {
  stop-color: #6bb7c7;
  stop-opacity: 0.1;
}

.lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom {
  stop-color: #6bb7c7;
  stop-opacity: 0.6;
}

.lineChart--svg {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.lineChart--xAxisTicks .domain, .lineChart--xAxis .domain, .lineChart--yAxisTicks .domain {
  display: none;
}

.lineChart--xAxis .tick line {
  display: none;
}

.lineChart--xAxisTicks .tick line, .lineChart--yAxisTicks .tick line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #b3b3b3;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 2,2;
}



/**
 * Helper classes
 */
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="charts--headline">Wanna check the code?<br>Click "Edit this pen" in left bottom corner.</h1>
<div class="charts--container">
  <ul>
    <li class="chart">
     
      <div id="pieChart">
        <svg id="pieChartSVG">
          <defs>
            <filter id='pieChartInsetShadow'>
              <feOffset dx='0' dy='0'/>
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='3' result='offset-blur' />
              <feComposite operator='out' in='SourceGraphic' in2='offset-blur' result='inverse' />
              <feFlood flood-color='black' flood-opacity='1' result='color' />
              <feComposite operator='in' in='color' in2='inverse' result='shadow' />
              <feComposite operator='over' in='shadow' in2='SourceGraphic' />
            </filter>
            <filter id="pieChartDropShadow">
              <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur" />
              <feOffset in="blur" dx="0" dy="3" result="offsetBlur" />
              <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode />
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
              </feMerge>
            </filter>
          </defs>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="chart">
      <h3 class="chart--subHeadline">Chart 2</h3>
      <h2 class="chart--headline">Area Label Would Go Here</h2>
      <div id="lineChart">
        <svg id="lineChartSVG" class="lineChart--svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
              <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top" offset="0%" />
              <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any Help will be really appreciated to overcome this issue.

Comment: Hi i want to change the size of the tool tip details the black pop up not the blue/white circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In above sample tooltip use svg path to create the bubble.

```
 details.append( 'path' )
          .attr( 'd', 'M2.99990186,0 C1.34310181,0 0,1.34216977 0,2.99898218 L0,47.6680579 C0,49.32435 1.34136094,50.6670401 3.00074875,50.6670401 L44.4095996,50.6670401 C48.9775098,54.3898926 44.4672607,50.6057129 49,54.46875 C53.4190918,50.6962891 49.0050244,54.4362793 53.501875,50.6670401 L94.9943116,50.6670401 C96.6543075,50.6670401 98,49.3248703 98,47.6680579 L98,2.99898218 C98,1.34269006 96.651936,0 95.0000981,0 L2.99990186,0 Z M2.99990186,0' )
          .attr( 'width', detailWidth )
          .attr( 'height', detailHeight );
```

to change the width of tooltip you need to change svg path values accordingly. you can use online svg editor to edit svg paths.